# The path determined by the three Lagrange equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Here is an excerpt from classical mechanics by John Taylor. What does the underline sentence mean?

> newton second law is $F=ma$, it doesn't determine the path, neither does the Lagrange equations.

[image]

Comment: *newton second law is F=ma, it doesn't determine the path...* How does N2L not determine the path?

Comment: I guess N2L is determine the acceleration?

Comment: Not clear. Where does the quoted sentence come from? It does not appear to be from the book in the image.

Answer (score 3):

> newton second law is F=ma, it doesn't determine the path

Yes, it does.

The force tells you the acceleration. The acceleration tells you how the velocity changes. The velocity tells you how the position changes. Thus if you know an object’s initial position, its initial velocity, and the force acting on it (as a function of its position and velocity), you can determine how it moves through space.

This is an absolutely fundamental part of classical mechanics, and is vastly more important to understand than the Lagrangian formalism.

The proper way to think about $\mathbf F=m\mathbf a$ is that it gives you a second-order differential equation

$$m\frac{d^2\mathbf r}{dt^2}=\mathbf F\left(\mathbf r, \frac{d\mathbf r}{dt}\right)$$

which, with the initial conditions for $\mathbf r$ and $\frac{d\mathbf r}{dt}$, you can solve to get the path $\mathbf r(t)$. If it cannot be solved analytically, it can always be solved numerically.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful! I didn't think about N2L that way.